# How to access complex types Argument in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, explicit-interface

I am trying to use one WCF service, since we don't have the service URL we got XSD and WSDL. At this point of time trying for POC stuff for that. Using `svcutil` tool genarated class file. I am not very much familiar with WCF stuff, so first trying to use these classes in C#.

Below is my complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace smsclient
{
    public interface ISendSms
    {
    sendMessageResponse1 sendMessage(sendMessageRequest request);
    }

    public class AccessSMSDetails: ISendSms
    {

  sendMessageResponse1 ISendSms.sendMessage(sendMessageRequest request)
        {
           //Here is my implementation code.          
            sendMessageResponse sresponse = new sendMessageResponse();
            sresponse.messageid = 1;
            sresponse.recipient = "Chiranjeevi";
            sresponse.reference = "reference";
            sresponse.status = "sucsesss";

            sendMessageResponse1 sresponse1 = new sendMessageResponse1(sresponse);
            return sresponse1;

        }
    }

    public class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sendMessage sm = new sendMessage();
            sm.content = "Content";
            sm.destination = "Destination";
            sm.reference = "reference";
            sendMessageRequest sRequest = new sendMessageRequest(sm);
            sendMessageResponse1 sclient = new sendMessageResponse1();
            AccessSMSDetails asms = new AccessSMSDetails();
          //sclient=            
          // Here I am not getting the interface Method name to call. Please correct Me if this approach is wrong.
        }
    }
}
```

In the last line I'm unable to call the interface method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [explicit interface implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Hence you need to cast the `asms` variable to the respective interface type for it to work:

```
((ISendSms)asms).sendMessage(…);
```

Alternatively, if possible in your case, use a non-explicit implementation:

```
public class AccessSMSDetails: ISendSms
{
    public sendMessageResponse1 sendMessage(sendMessageRequest request)
    {
    }
}
```

and then you can call the method as usual:

```
asms.sendMessage(…);
```

Comment: @Tunchy: If i add below line getting exception.                                    sclient=     ((ISendSms)asms).sendMessage(sRequest);                                     Error 1 'smsclient.AccessSMSDetails' does not implement interface member 'smsclient.ISendSms.sendMessage()'  line no :169 18 smsclient

Comment: Why to cast when we can declare!

Comment: @Amit Because he may need to access the full class, not just the interface…

Comment: May is good thing but current class contains only interface implementation.

Comment: @Chiranjeevi Then you are, likely, not showing the complete, up-to-date code in your question.

Comment: @Tunchy:no this is the only code i am using, actually this is genarated code from wsdl and xsd for wcf service, to create a client for understanding made this class structure.When I will consume  i need only interface method in my client.

Comment: The code in from your question with this exact line: `((ISendSms)asms).sendMessage(null);` added instead of the `// Here I am not getting …` comment *just compiles **fine***.

Comment: @Tunchy: Thank you so much it worked for me, now i will try to create Wcf service and client with this I hope.Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
ISendSms asms = new AccessSMSDetails();
asms.sendMessage(request);
```